# Qt Creator Assembly Output - LEA instruction

Tags: qt, assembly, x86, qt-creator

Qt shows me assembler (x86) command this way:

```
lea    (%edx,%eax,1),%ecx
```

What does it means? I can't find description of this instruction that fits.

**UPD**

Thanks. So, am i correct?

0) movl   $0x0,-0x14(%ebp)

1) mov    -0x14(%ebp),%eax

2) inc    %eax

3) mov    %eax,-0x14(%ebp)

4) mov    -0x14(%ebp),%eax

5) inc    %eax

6) mov    %eax,-0x14(%ebp)

7) mov    -0x14(%ebp),%edx

8) mov    -0x14(%ebp),%eax

9) lea    (%edx,%eax,1),%ecx

10) mov    %ecx,-0x14(%ebp)

11) inc    %edx

12) mov    %edx,-0x14(%ebp)

13) inc    %eax

14) mov    %eax,-0x14(%ebp)

Makes this("i" is "-0x14(%ebp)"):

0) i=0

1) eax=0

2) eax=1

3) i=1

4) eax=1

5) eax=2

6) i=2

7) edx=2

8) eax=2

9) ecx=2; ecx=4

10) i=4

11) edx=3

12) i=3

13) eax=3

14) i=3

Comment: Wait, what? What do you mean, Qt shows you assembler?

Comment: Yep, and i want to see it :) Now i want to figure out what is this instruction do?

Comment: It means Load Effective Address. What are you asking about, exactly?

Comment: Exactly - what means "source" part (%edx,%eax,1). What goes to %ecx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LEA` stands for Load Effective Address.  It's used to perform an address computation, but then rather than accessing the value at that address it stores the computed address in the destination register.

In this case, it's storing the value of EDX + (EAX * 1) into ECX.  This is an alternative to the two-instruction sequence

```
movl %edx, %ecx
addl %eax, %ecx
```

Comment: Thanks. So, am i correct?
0) movl   $0x0,-0x14(%ebp)
1) mov    -0x14(%ebp),%eax
2) inc    %eax
3) mov    %eax,-0x14(%ebp)
4) mov    -0x14(%ebp),%eax
5) inc    %eax
6) mov    %eax,-0x14(%ebp)
7) mov    -0x14(%ebp),%edx
8) mov    -0x14(%ebp),%eax
9) lea    (%edx,%eax,1),%ecx
10) mov    %ecx,-0x14(%ebp)
11) inc    %edx
12) mov    %edx,-0x14(%ebp)
13) inc    %eax
14) mov    %eax,-0x14(%ebp)
Makes this("i" is "-0x14(%ebp)"): 
0) i=0
1) eax=0
2) eax=1
3) i=1
4) eax=1
5) eax=2
6) i=2
7) edx=2
8) eax=2
9) ecx=2; ecx=4
10) i=4
11) edx=3
12) i=3
13) eax=3
14) i=3

Comment: EEK! Wall of code in a comment!  You might want to edit that into your question.

Comment: Done. It's in the question :)